# failed to publish events: temporary bulk send failure

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

When i try to create multiple index in filebeat.yml and output to elasticsearch, i am getting temporary bulk send failure error. This is coming only when i introduce ilm as disable. can anyone help

Below is the filebeat config

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  id: denali
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/denali/denali.log
  parsers:
    - multiline:
        type: pattern
        pattern: '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'
        negate: true
        match: after
  fields:
    app_id: denali

- type: filestream
  id: freeswitch
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/freeswitch/freeswitch.log
  parsers:
    - multiline:
        type: pattern
        pattern: '^((\d|[a-z]|-)+ \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'
        negate: true
        match: after
  fields:
    app_id: freeswitch

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

setup.template.enabled: true
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.template.overwrite: true
setup.template.name: "index-%{[agent.version]}"
setup.template.pattern: "index-%{[agent.version]}-*"

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["ip:port"]
  index: "index-%{[agent.version]}-%{[fields.app_id]:other}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  protocol: "http"

processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["agent.ephemeral_id", "agent.hostname", "agent.id", "agent.name", "agent.type", "agent.version", "cloud.account.id", "cloud.provider", "cloud.service.name", "container.id", "container.image.name", "container.labels.COMMIT", "container.labels.PIPELINE_URL", "container.labels.PROJECT_NAME", "container.labels.PROJECT_URL", "container.labels.SOURCE_BRANCH", "container.labels.TimeStamp", "container.labels.RELEASEARTIFACT_VERSION", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_config-hash", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_container-number", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_oneoff", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_project", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_project_config_files", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_project_working_dir", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_service", "container.labels.com_docker_compose_version", "ecs.version", "host.architecture", "host.containerized", "host.id", "host.mac", "host.os.codename", "host.os.family", "host.os.kernel", "host.os.name", "host.os.platform", "host.os.type", "host.os.version", "log.offset"]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ramanichandran can you please provide the error logs from filebeat? Also, do you see any errors on ES logs when filebeat is trying to send logs for ingestion?

I don't believe it's due to creation of multiple indices since you are essentially creating only 3 indices. I have configured filebeat to create about 15 indices in my use case and it works just fine where my config is similar to yours with ILM disabled.

It's worth trying to set following attributes for output.elasticsearch:

```
bulk_max_size: 25
bulk_max_bytes: 104857600
```

Comment: Hi Ayush, Thanks for the response. I have shared the link for filebeat logs for your ref. I think it is due to life cycle management. If i disable ilm this error is not coming. Please click on this link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OEPaDMOM-pjcckmILMvrUa7GxvdMtCeF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why are you using filebeat version 7.17.8 with Elasticsearch version 7.10.1 ? You should always run your stack components on the same version since there are regular updates on document mapping/ type and ECS.
Can you try running filebeat 7.10.1 or even better, upgrade ES to 7.17.8 (best would be to use latest versions of all stack components imho) ?

Comment: I dont think so, you can find the compatible versions here, https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility

Comment: Right, may be try setting the index names like this:
`
  output.elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["ip:port"]
    index: "index-%{[agent.version]}-other-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    indices:
      - index: "index-%{[agent.version]}-%{[fields.app_id]:denali}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
        when:
          - contains:
              fields.app_id: "denali"
      - index: "index-%{[agent.version]}-%{[fields.app_id]:freeswitch}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
        when:
          - contains:
              fields.app_id: "freeswitch"
    protocol: "http"
`

Comment: Also, the logs you've shared doesn't say much about the issue. Will it be possible to share full logs from filebeat and Elasticsearch both ?